# Does "catch your breath" mean either "stop breathing" or "start breathing again"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

The 2 dictionaries gave the 2 opposite definitions

> **[catch your breath](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/breath?q=breath)**: ​to stop breathing for a moment because of fear, shock, etc.
>
> When he said he had resigned, I caught my breath in surprise.

---

> **[catch your breath](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/catch-your-breath)**: to start breathing normally again after running or making a lot of effort
>
> Slow down, I need to catch my breath.

I felt that British and American people use "**catch your breath**" differently. In British English, "**catch your breath**" means to stop breathing but In American English, it means to start bathing again.

However, I am not sure if it is true.

Does "**catch your breath**" mean either "**stop breathing**" or "**start breathing again**"?

Also, what is the difference between "**catch your breath**" and "**hold your breath**"?

Answer (score 2):

Your summation of the Oxford's definition is misleading. The full form documents both meanings:

> catch your breath
>
> - ​to stop breathing for a moment because of fear, shock, etc.
>
>   When he said he had resigned, I caught my breath in surprise.
>   ​- (also get your breath (again/back) British English)
>
>   to start to be able to breathe normally again after running or doing exercise that makes you tired

...and a few dozen lines lower...

> get your breath (again/back) (British English) 
> (also catch your breath North American English, British English)
>
> ​to breathe normally again after running or doing exercise that makes you tired
>
> I needed a few minutes to get my breath back after the run. 
>     She paused to catch her breath.

Addressing your points/questions:

> In British English, "catch your breath" means to stop breathing but In American English, it means to start bathing again.

In British English, it can mean either - but it's pretty obvious which is intended in the example sentences above.  Just consider whether the situation involves shock/surprise that would cause a sudden, unplanned interruption to breathing (possibly with a sharp inhalation, or just stopping), or whether there's been intense exercise so someone would need a rest to gradually slow breathing to normal rhythm/volume.

> Also, what is the difference between "catch your breath" and "hold your breath"?

Even in the "stop breathing" sense, "catch your breath" implies a sudden, involuntary or instinctive reaction.  "I heard the killer's footsteps outside the door and caught my breath, freezing in place".  "hold you breath" sounds more premeditated or deliberate - "I would have to hold my breath for 20 seconds to swim that far underwater".

Comment: The Longman link also gives both definitions, if you scroll down a bit (and the examples include both usages).